recieving 404 not found error after submitting a form
i know it's a silly issue but I am at the very beginning stage of learning Laravel without any guidance or help from anyone. so please, don't mind. I'll delete it after getting the answer.
I am using Laravel with react inertia. i am submitting a form from '/p/create' to '/p' route that is returning me 404 not found error. can't find what went wrong here.
My routes:
Route::get('/p/create', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Posts');
})->name('posts.create');

Route::post('/p', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.store');


my PostController:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function store()
    {
        dd(request()->all())
    }
}


The form of '/p/create'

export default function Posts({ auth }) {
    return (
        <div className="post">
            <Navbar auth={auth} />

            <form
                encType="multipart/form-data"
                action="{{ route('posts.store') }}"
                method="POST"
            >
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="_token"
                    value="{!! csrf_token() !!}"
                />

                <input type="file" name="image" />
                <textarea name="caption" />
                <button type="submit">Post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}


my route List:
PS E:\PHP projects\new and final\back\Instagram> php artisan route:list

  GET|HEAD  / .................................................................................. generated::1UHNC2h1AcGloyZQ
  POST      _ignition/execute-solution ....... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController  
  GET|HEAD  _ignition/health-check ................... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController  
  POST      _ignition/update-config ................ ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
  GET|HEAD  confirm-password .................................... password.confirm › Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@show  
  POST      confirm-password ........................ generated::vG6ZS3cMZcBju2hz › Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@store  
  GET|HEAD  dashboard ............................................................................................ dashboard  
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/{user} ................................................................................ dashboard.user  
  POST      email/verification-notification ......... verification.send › Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController@store  
  GET|HEAD  forgot-password ..................................... password.request › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@create  
  POST      forgot-password ........................................ password.email › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@store  
  GET|HEAD  login ....................................................... login › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@create  
  POST      login .................................. generated::WxuQbzVnBo7s2ikB › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@store  
  POST      logout .................................................... logout › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@destroy  
  POST      p ........................................................................... posts.store › PostController@store  
  GET|HEAD  p/create .......................................................................................... posts.create
  PUT       password ...................................................... password.update › Auth\PasswordController@update  
  GET|HEAD  profile .................................................................. profile.edit › ProfileController@edit  
  PATCH     profile .............................................................. profile.update › ProfileController@update  
  DELETE    profile ............................................................ profile.destroy › ProfileController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD  register ....................................................... register › Auth\RegisteredUserController@create  
  POST      register ..................................... generated::UZNwLO2B8FS0PVb4 › Auth\RegisteredUserController@store  
  POST      reset-password ............................................... password.store › Auth\NewPasswordController@store  
  GET|HEAD  reset-password/{token} ...................................... password.reset › Auth\NewPasswordController@create  
  GET|HEAD  sanctum/csrf-cookie .......................... sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show  
  GET|HEAD  up ................................................................................. generated::pquyE3RwESLgrYla
  GET|HEAD  verify-email ...................................... verification.notice › Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController  
  GET|HEAD  verify-email/{id}/{hash} ...................................... verification.verify › Auth\VerifyEmailController  



{{ route('posts.store') }} There is no route with that name

Not sure why you changed/edited your route from {{ route('posts.store') }} to {{ route('posts') }} - but the same applies: there is no route with a name of posts

You defined your "post" route without a name attribute. Change it to this:
Route::post('/p', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.store');

And then, you will be able to use it like this:
action="{{ route('posts.store') }}"

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#named-routes

nope, still getting the error

Can you do php artisan route:list and paste the result of that command in your question?

i am reciving PostController doesn't exist error. but i have postcontroller here

In that case, either your import is wrong in the web.php (or not imported at all), or the namespace on your PostController is wrong, meaning that your controller is nested on some other directory inside app/Http/Controllers

i have rechacked them. they are all fine and it's still not working

i added the route list. please check them

You missed your route name, just change your route to this:
Route::post('/p', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.store');


nope, still getting the error

is it ok when you use '/p' instead of {{ route('posts.store') }} ?

@NaimurSharon If it doesn't work make sure the route shows up (with the correct name) in php artisan route:list. If it doesn't, try to clear the route cache: php artisan route:clear

i am recieving PostController doesn't exist error afrer running php artisan route:list

You should add use App\Http\Controllers\PostController; or controller directory to your route file, also check names.

yes, i have added it and it's still not working

@NaimurSharon Please edit your question and append your changed code so we know what we're working with here. "it's still not working" doesn't help anybody, please always post the complete error message you get. Is it still the 404 or the "PostController doesn't exist" error?

i have changed them and added the route lists too. please check

update your web.php file with complete file and attach image of your controllers directory.

Here is a solution that is working for me.
// Controller call in route file
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

// Route define
Route::post("/p", [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('store');

// Use in view file
action="{{ route('store') }}"


yes, i have used them and it's still not working
